# How to format entered date in mysql to timestamp format?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I format a date to a timestamp in MySQL?

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE order_date BETWEEN('2011-01-01 00:00:00') AND ('2011-01-31 23:59:59');
```

In my table I have a date which is a timestamp, so if I run the query above it doesn't show any result.

What I want is after inserting two dates in order_date my date will automatically converted to a timestamp like this:

```
1334230309
```

So if I entered a format like this 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', the query should run and return the orders between Jan 01,2011 and Jan 31,2011

Comment: Have you tried the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i solved my issue thanks to sir Eric. I used UNIX_TIMESTAMP()

Answer (score 1):

covert the time in the query to time stamp 2011-01-01 00:00:00 to 1334200005 and use it in query

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN('1334200005') AND('1334200305');
```

Comment: what i want is to automatically convert my date to mysql timestamp using a query.

Comment: Old answer now but I have no idea how this could possibly receive any up votes... Couldn't possibly be of any use to anyone.